# Ruby Method Chaining (beginner)

Tags: ruby, method-chaining

I wrote the code below:

```
class Pet
  attr_accessor :breed, :name, :weight

  def initialize(breed, name, weight)
    @breed = breed
    @name = name
    @weight = weight
  end

  def show_pet
    p "Your pet is a #{@breed}, and their name is #{@name}. They weigh #{@weight} lbs."
  end

  def set_weight(weight)
    @weight += weight
    self
  end
end

pet1 = Pet.new("Chihuahua", "Jill", 5)
pet1.set_weight(5).show_pet
```

but I don't fully understand how it works, primarily the `self` part. I hope someone could point me to a good explanation for method chaining.

Comment: Returning `self` is a way to provide a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). It allows you to send several methods to the same receiver by chaining the method calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple of thing to consider if you are a beginner.

The last value call in a method is the return value of the methods. In your example :

```rb
def set_weight(weight)
    @weight += weight
    self
end
```

is equivalent to :

```rb
def set_weight(weight)
    @weight += weight
    return self # <- with return
end
```

Then, about **self**, if you are used to other language, you may have seen the keyword **this**, it is equivalent.
It is a referent of the instance of the class you are currently using.

As you are returning **self** you can chain the call like :

```rb
rex_the_dog = Pet.new nil, 'rex', 20 #create rex_the_dog an instance of Pet
rex_the_dog.set_weight(3).set_weight(2) #As you return self, you can chain call like this
rex_the_dog.weight #return 25  (20 : set on init + 2 : first set_weight call + 3 : second set_weight call)
```

Answer (score 1):

`show_pet` is an instance method of `Pet` (just like `set_weight`), and so it can be called only on instances of `Pet`. When you want to call this method after `set_weight` as you did, `set_weight` needs to return the instance of `Pet` that it was called on.

`self` is the return value you've set in `set_weight(weight)`, and inside an instance method, this is a reference to the `Pet` instance you're calling the method on. So whenever an instance of `Pet` calls that method, it returns the instance itself.

To see this more clearly, you could experiment a little by doing something like this:

```
class Pet 
  ...
  def return_instance
    self
  end
end

pet1 = Pet.new('Chihuaha', 'Jill', 5)
pet1 == pet1.return_instance # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example the `@weight` is an instance variable and the set_weight is an instance method which adds weight to the instance variable `@weight`.
`self` returns the instance of the class with the updated `@weight`.

The `show_pet` method then called on the returned instance and prints its values.